# How do I invoke a WSE3.0 service to be deployed to Windows Server 2008?

Tags: wcf, web-services, windows-server-2008, wse3.0

One of our C# ASP.Net projects has some dependencies on the Microsoft WSE 3.0 library, in order to consume a WSE3.0 web service. However, we're migrating the project to Windows Server 2008, which does not support WSE3.0.

So I need to refactor the code to remove the dependency to WSE 3.0 but still maintain its functionality. The code is simply adding a username security token to the SOAP context and then invoking the web service. I'm not sure where to start though. I suspect I switch to WCF, and if so, is there any tutorial available online to help?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by creating a simple application, maybe a Console application, to be a test consumer of the existing web service. Create client proxy classes for this application by using "Add Service Reference", and pointing it to the existing WSE service. That should take care of most of the problems.

Once the simple console application works, you can do the same for your ASP.NET project.

Needless to say, it's way past time to update that WSE service to WCF, which is supported, and which will continue to be supported for a long time to come.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/migrating-wse-3-0-web-services-to-wcf) is a pretty good rundown of the differences between WSE 3.0 & WCF and migration recommendations. I'd start by getting the migrated service to run under the basicHttpBinding configuration (without user name/password authentication).

Once the service is running as expected and look at this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815091929/http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/03/15/username-password-amp-ws-security-with-silverlight.aspx) to see how to get the migrated service configured for user name/password authentication. The article is written for Silverlight use but there should be enough in it to get you going.